# How to change arcgis map for kotlin locationDisplay mode in jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-view, arcgis-android-api

I successfully integrated an ArcGIS MapView within a composable layout, and the map rendered flawlessly. Subsequently, I activated the location display mode, which functioned as expected.

```
    val mapView by lazy { MapView(context) }
    val locationDisplay = mapView.locationDisplay

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        // listen to changes in the status of the location data source
        locationDisplay.dataSource.start().onFailure {
            println(it.message)
        }
    }


  AndroidView(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    factory = { context ->
        mapView.also { mapView ->
            mapView.apply {
                locationDisplay.setAutoPanMode(LocationDisplayAutoPanMode.CompassNavigation)
            }
        }
    },
    update = { view -> // view is automatically cast to a MapView
        ...
    }
)
```

Here is my problem:

I want to change Arcgis locationDisplay mode by a button click, so I created a button outside the AndroidView component, writed a clickable function to set the locationDisplay mode to **LocationDisplayAutoPanMode.Recenter**, but it did not work as I expected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the **localtionDisplay** should be **remembered**
in the compose, and the value could be stored in the composition during the initial composition and the stored value is returned during recomposition. Here is my adjusted code:

```
 val mapView by lazy { MapView(context) }
 val locationDisplay = remember {mapView.locationDisplay}

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        // listen to changes in the status of the location data source
        locationDisplay.dataSource.start().onFailure {
            println(it.message)
        }
    }


  AndroidView(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    factory = { context ->
        mapView.also { mapView ->
            mapView.apply {
                locationDisplay.setAutoPanMode(LocationDisplayAutoPanMode.CompassNavigation)
            }
        }
    },
    update = { view -> // view is automatically cast to a MapView
        ...
    }
)
```